# How can I use `def` in Jenkins Pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I am learning [Jenkins Pipeline](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/), and I tried to follow this Pipeline [code](https://github.com/azure-devops/movie-db-java-on-azure/blob/master/Jenkinsfile-data-app#L19). But my Jenkins always complains that `def` is not legal.

I am wondering did I miss any plugins? I already installed `groovy`, `job-dsl`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: There are 2 types of pipelines: scripted and declarative. Certain things can't be used in part of the declarative pipeline. Learn the difference between the two and you should learn where `def` is valid.

Comment: Thanks for your hints, it leads to the answer. `def` is used in scripted pipeline, which start with `node {...}`; while my file starts with `pipeline`, which is declarative, and `def` is not allowed, unless it is wrapped by `script {...}`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As @Rob said, There are 2 types of pipelines: `scripted` and `declarative`. It is like `imperative` vs `declarative`. `def` is only allowed in `scripted` pipeline or wrapped in `script {}`.

### Scripted pipeline (Imperative)

Start with `node`, and `def` or `if` is allowed, like below. It is  traditional way.

```
node {
    stage('Example') {
        if (env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master') {
            echo 'I only execute on the master branch'
        } else {
            echo 'I execute elsewhere'
        }
    }
}
```

### Declarative pipeline (Preferred)

Start with `pipeline`, and `def` or `if` is NOT allowed, unless it is wrapped in `script {...}`. Declarative pipeline make a lot things easy to write and read.

#### time trigger

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    triggers {
        cron('H 4/* 0 0 1-5')
    }
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            steps {
                echo 'Hello World'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### when

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Example Build') {
            steps {
                echo 'Hello World'
            }
        }
        stage('Example Deploy') {
            when {
                branch 'production'
            }
            steps {
                echo 'Deploying'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Parallel

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Non-Parallel Stage') {
            steps {
                echo 'This stage will be executed first.'
            }
        }
        stage('Parallel Stage') {
            when {
                branch 'master'
            }
            failFast true
            parallel {
                stage('Branch A') {
                    agent {
                        label "for-branch-a"
                    }
                    steps {
                        echo "On Branch A"
                    }
                }
                stage('Branch B') {
                    agent {
                        label "for-branch-b"
                    }
                    steps {
                        echo "On Branch B"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### embedded with scripted code

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            steps {
                echo 'Hello World'

                script {
                    def browsers = ['chrome', 'firefox']
                    for (int i = 0; i < browsers.size(); ++i) {
                        echo "Testing the ${browsers[i]} browser"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To read more declarative pipeline grammar, please refer the official doc [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/)

Comment: See my example of it above as an alternative way to use it on a declarative pipeline

Answer (score 10):

You can use def with a declarative pipeline, just not inside it eg

```
def agentLabel
if (BRANCH_NAME =~ /^(staging|master)$/)  {
    agentLabel = "prod"
} else {
    agentLabel = "master"
}

pipeline {
  agent { node { label agentLabel } } 
..
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use `def` by using `node` like below:

```
node {
stage('Example') {
    if (env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master') {
        echo 'I only execute on the master branch'
    } else {
        echo 'I execute elsewhere'
    }
}
```

Another way : by using `script{..}`

```
    stage ('jon'){
steps{
script{                                                                                              
    def imageLine = 'chiducaff/user_containers:sonnginx'
}
    writeFile file: 'anchore_images', text: imageLine
    anchore name: 'anchore_images'
                           }}
```

Comment: The latter form doesn't work. It seems you have to use the variable within the `script` block or you get `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException` for it.